# How can I select string after = operator in a file?

Tags: java

I have a file containing following text:

```
CompanyName=IBM
Name=User1234
CompanyName=Google
```

How can check if a text 'CompanyName' exists in a text file, if it does then select a string after = operator?. So the text from above file should output IBM and Google.

```
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);

        }
```

Comment: A couple of options: a) regular expressions; b) indexOf and substring...

Comment: You need to read all lines (or line by line) and search-compare.

Comment: I recommend using `String result=line.split("=", 2)[1];` to get that the second part.

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible to get a small example?

Comment: No, you should take those hints and try it for yourself. Currently you've shown no effort - no indication of what you've already tried, what went wrong, etc.

Comment: you should use properties here.
check this http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be something like this?

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    System.out.println(line);

    if(line.contains("CompanyName"))
    {
        String[] splits = line.split("=");
        String desired = splits[1]; // second position in the string array.
    }
}
```

EDIT: adding more functionality in getting the other fields at the same time.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            String compName = "";
            String name = "";
            if(line.contains("CompanyName"))
            {
                String[] splits2 = line.split("=");
                compName = splits2[1]; // second position in the string array.
                if((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    String[] splits = line.split("=");
                    name = splits[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. Lets say if I added another If loop after above If loop to check for ProductCode text this time. Is there a way I can combine the output from first if loop with second If loop, so the results should look like: IBM 1111 (where IBM is a companyName & 1111 is a ProductCode)
Google 2222

Comment: Sure thing, give me a minute to write it out

Comment: Yes this looks fine but one question where are you checking for the ProductCode text in your code. I can see your checking CompanyName text?

Comment: Accidentally forgot to add  ( ) in the if statement. Thats why you're getting the incompatible types error. I don't see anything in your question relating to ProductCode text. Could you clarify this?

Comment: So if I want to search for ProductCode text in the same file and combine results with CompanyName, how can I do that? So search for two text and print the results at the end

Comment: In order to find instances of ProductCode in the text document, you would have the exact same if-statement asking if the line contains the characters "CompanyName". Just do another if br.readLine is not null and then ask if the line contains "ProductCode". If you are dealing with a lot of variables in a text document, I recommend storing these values in a separate java class with attributes like: "companyName", "name", "productCode" and then cycle through that array of custom objects at the end of the program.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.util.Properties`

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new InputStreamReader
        (new FileInputStream("myprops.properties"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String property = properties.getProperty("CompanyName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
function findValueOfAttr(String attr, br) {

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

  if (line.indexOf(attr) == 0)
     return line.subString(line.indexOf("=")+1);
   }

  return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain me the IF loop please? what do you mean by this line (line.indexOf(attr) == 0)? and where are you checking if CompanyName text equals?

Comment: Let's suppose your  attribute is "companyName".  Then the if loop will check the position of the string "companyName" on that time.  If it is at position 0 (meaning the beginning of the row),  then the attribute exists.  Next, to get the value, I get the position of the equal sign, add 1 to it,  and I take the rest of the line and return it.